# Cannot send information between multiple clients connected to a server

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I have multiple clients connected to a server. Each time the server sends a string which contains the IP and address of client 1 to client 2, client 2 connects to client 1 and sends it a message.

Server and clients are local; they have same IP but different listening ports.

I get the following error: Transport endpoint is already connected.

After debugging, I think it is because of the same IP address, although i don't understand why it doesn't connect through the port. Client 2 gets the correct port of client 1.

(note: i omitted the error handling)

Here's the code:

```
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0); //the one for the server
   sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0); //the one for the client

   //creating client
  client.sin_family = AF_INET;
  client.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[3])); // the port is read from command line
  client.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  //bind
  int b = bind(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

  //listen
  listen(sockfd2,1); //only 1 client can connect to this one!

  //creating server
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[5])); // the port is read from command line
  inet_aton(argv[4], &serv_addr.sin_addr);


  connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

  while(1){
  ... // the client connects to the server and gets the string

  destination.sin_family = AF_INET;
  destination.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(address); 
  destination.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));

  //this line gives the error
  if(connect(sockfd2,(struct sockaddr*)&destination, sizeof(destination)<0)
        error("Error connecting");

  //the sending
  n = send(sockfd2, message, strlen(message), 0);
  if(n<0) 
        error("Error sending"); 

  ....


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`sockfd2` which you try to `connect()` is already bound, and assigned a role (by means of `listen`) to be a server socket. Basically the only valid operation it can do is to `accept()` an incoming connection.

Comment: So if I accept, i receive a new sockfd. Can I use that new sockfd to read/write information?

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see what I get.